# A single word desribing creature with misshapen and obscure features?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm trying to find the best way to describe being so physically deformed, that its only, somewhat recognizable, feature is its own body shape. *Mutant* doesn't work for me, as it implies the reason of deformation, and I need something more general. *Freak* seams right, but sounds silly to me, so I hopping for something else. I was thinking about word *chimera*, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to use it.

Also, I don't care how offensive the word is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you are looking for is ***gargoyle***.

Although coined in connection with carvings and sculptures (grotesquely carved waterspout), [Gargoyle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gargoyle?s=t) can be applied to a person with a grotesque appearance.

An intriguing word is ***invunche***, a monstrous human creature from a disturbing South American legend. One of these can be seen on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qt0tiqxqyGU) - you don't forget the image easily after reading the legend.

Comment: Yes, I think that's it. Thank you. So many times I drawn gargoyles, but for some reason the word slip my mind completely.

Answer (score 3):

How does *aberration* or *anomaly* sound to you?

Comment: +1 for aberration. It might not get better than that

Comment: Great, nice to see you've found your suitable word.

Comment: That wasn't me, sorry. Actually I've never heard the word *aberration* being used, so I'm not gonna use It as well. But I'm gonna check it out, thank you.

Comment: great :) you could just check the thesaurus for a larger variety of words

Answer (score 2):

#### *ogre*

> A person who is felt to be particularly cruel, brutish, **or hideous**.

There's always your *grotesque* of course (n. & adj.). I you happen to be in need of something more neutral, you can settle for *mangled*, and to remain perfectly objective, you can go with *disfigured*.

Comment: *Mangled* seams like such an expressive word. Is it commonly used? I don't think I hear it before. Thank you.

Comment: The word is not too common, but I've seen it used in more than one register: conversational, journalistic, literary, and also academic. Expressive is an understatement. I shudder to say it, but I find the word onomatopoeic. I know, gross. From COCA: _Till's skull was falling off and his mangled face revealed how horribly he had been beaten for allegedly " whistling at a White woman._ But it's not pejorative, like ogre.

Comment: I've really learn something just now. Thanks again.